# Import error from parent directory in Python 3.6.9

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

## Problem

Hi. I'm having issues importing a module I wrote. The module I want to import is called `neural_networks`, defined in the `neural_networks.py` file.

**Directory tree**:

```
├── neural_networks.py
└── directory
    ├── neural_networks.py
    └── calling_module.py
```

**neural_networks.py**

```
def function_to_import():
    pass
```

I read Python 3 docs in the section [5.7. Package Relative Imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports), and applyed what's written there, but it's not all working.

**calling_module.py**

```
// ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
from . import neural_networks

// SyntaxError: invalid syntax
import ..neural_networks

// ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
from ..directory import neural_networks

// SyntaxError: invalid syntax
import .neural_networks

// works and i can use function_to_import() using neural_networks.function_to_import()
import neural_networks
```

## Question

How can I correctly import and use `neural_networks` module in `calling_module`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add the parent path using `sys` before calling other imports :

```py
import sys

sys.path.append("..")
```

Then :

```py
from neural_networks import neural_networks
```

In addition, you can add an `__init__.py` file (empty) in the directory containing the `.py` to import.

Answer (score 2):

@tlentali has answered the correct way but If you want to use absolute path instead of the relative path, you can do it like this

```
import os,inspect,sys
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
sys.path.append(parent_dir)
```

and then just import it,

```
from neural_networks import neural_networks
```

Comment: Thanks @LakshikaParihar, I appreciate and I take note !